# mdx escape character CDE Pentaho

Tags: escaping, mdx, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have seen some questions about MDX  escape character, but they focus on a query that has a value specified. I have a dynamic mdx, with values that will be specified by the user. This is the MDX:

```
    SELECT
    NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[INDICADOR]})} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[NOW].[NOW].Members})} ON ROWS
    FROM [UNION_NOW]
    WHERE CrossJoin({[PARENT].[${parentParameter}]}
```

the wild card is based on my selector:

```
    SELECT
    NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[NOW].[NOW].Members})} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[PARENT].[PARENT].Members})} ON ROWS
    FROM [UNION_NOW]
```

How do I apply the "escape value" in this case?

Comment: why is there a `crossjoin` in the `WHERE` clause of the first script? `WHERE CrossJoin({[PARENT].[${parentParameter}]}`

Comment: that MDX was created by the SAIKU Wizard, I'm not sure why there is a crossjoin, I'm still trying to understand the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve will be to use the PRE/POST execution events of selection component depending upon which CDE components are you using.

For similar situation

- I used a select component which was bringing data from a SQL query
- Based on user selection, I used the pre execution event of Query Component to generate a where clause and set that where clause in a "simple parameter" component
- and finally in the MDX Query used that simple parameter to join the dynamic where clause.

You can also use the post execution of select component to generate a dynamic where clause and set it in a parameter, and then use the parameter in your MDX/SQL query

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.
 
I'm still trying to understand the tool while I'm using it.
I have created already a select component with a simple parameter, the ${parentParameter} comes from it. 

Let me explain better whats going on, my first MDX is for a chart, and the second for a selector. When the user chooses a value that has the special character "[]" the chart receives an error since the "[]" is part of the MDX syntax.  I have to escape the "[]" before the chart execution. 

Can do that condition on the Query Component that you mentioned? And If so, do have an example?

Comment: okay, I do not have an example of it. but this is exactly the kind of things i have gone through. Try this and I am going to try to be more specific
- Create a new parameter in your report call it param_chart and have your chart run on this parameter rather than your parentParemeter
- Goto your select component, goto advanced properties, goto post execution and write the script as 
     function fn() { 
       myvalue = $("parentParameter").val();
        myvalue = myvalue.replace("[","").replace("]",""); 
      $("param_chart").val(myvalue);
     }

Comment: It works, the last doubt is that the chart is not changing with my selector, is it because of the property value of my param_chart?

Comment: I am guessing you already figured it out but if you have not.. You will need to set the LISTENERS of your chart to PARAM_chart that you created. This way every time PARAM_CHART changes the chart will refresh.